# Deserealizer for $httpParamSerializerJQLike

Tags: angularjs, url-encoding

[$httpParamSerializerJQLike](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$httpParamSerializerJQLike) does great job serializing the objects to put them as GET-parameters:

```
console.log($httpParamSerializerJQLike({a: "hi", "b": "hi again", arr: ["myarray", "be", 1]}));
// a=hi&arr%5B%5D=myarray&arr%5B%5D=be&arr%5B%5D=1&b=hi+again
```

What I want is to decode these parameters back to the object. What service should I use for that in AngularJS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `$location` service. First call `$location.search(yourUrl)`, than `$location.search()` to get parsed object.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location#search

Comment: In my particular case that's a good alternative, thanks.  It's just strange that there's no separate deserealization function for this serializer. I thought it should be symmetrical...